# RequiredFieldValidator inside EditItemTemplate of a DataList stays invisible

Tags: asp.net

I have the following portion in my EditItemTemplate

```
<asp:TableCell ID="td1" runat="server" ColumnSpan="3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpNo")%>' />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="CallOut" ID="vldReqEmpNumber" runat="server" Visible="true"
                ValidationGroup="Edit"  ControlToValidate="txtEmpNo" Text="*<br />Emp Number is required" ErrorMessage="Emp Number field cannot be left blank" Display="Dynamic" />

</asp:TableCell>
```

When the page is running in Chrome, I hit edit on one of the Rows of the DataList. I see the edit text box, but when in Chrome Dev Console I type in `Page_Validators` it does not return any SPAN elements. What am I missing? I have already tried other discussions I found on SO and other websites. I also noticed that in the `ItemDataBound` event, the validator's Visible property is always set to false, even in the Watch window when I tried to set it to true, it changes to false.

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Here you assigned validation group, so can you please make sure you have assigned same for button?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, very silly reason

The  that is not shown in the question which wraps what's shown had visible=false. But what I fail to understand is, why was the TextBox visible?